# Fail to build the master branch of elasticsearch using gradle

Tags: elasticsearch, build

I am using the gradle 2.8 and java 1.8.0_20 to build the master branch of the elasticsearch and get the error:

```
AutoExpandReplicas.java:44 : cannot assign to the final variable min
min = Integer.parseInt(sMin);
```

I have searched the google and there is no answer.
Here is the question: how can I build the elasticsearch?

Comment: See this: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/16097 It should work with Java 1.8.0_40

Comment: I used the java 1.8.0_40 and get the error: :core:forbiddenApisTest FAILED  @Val